# <button> inside <a> is reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have an react app with structure like this.

```
 private navigate(){
    alert("navigate");
}

<a href="#gotothisid">
   <button onclick="navigate()"></button>
</a>
<div id="gotothisid">
</div>
```

On click, the page is reloading after the alert but it should just shift the focus to #gotothisid.

What is missing here? Is there anyway to achieve both button click and a href together without reloading the page?

I want to achieve both button click and a href together without reloading the page.

Comment: Be careful of functions that shadow global names like `navigate()` which shadows window.navigate. You probably mean to reference the local value. See the curly brackets in onclick at https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: typo `]` in id (div), need to be `=`. also, the button need to have `e.preventDefault()` or something like that (edit: see Nico_ answer)

Comment: I have tried e.stopPropagation(). WIll try preventDefault() now

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of a button is `submit`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type.

You just have to add:

`<button onclick="navigate()" type="button"></button>`

so your button won't trigger a submit that reload the page.